# How to add/sum two values in hibernate/java

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee

Hello guys i need your help.
I want to add a stock to my existing quantity. 
For example in my jsp form, i have to input stock to be added in my quantity. If i have 10 quantity and i input 5stock. The quantity will now become 15.

My Controller looks this:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/updateUser")
public String updateUser(HttpServletRequest request, ModelMap map) {

    String searchId = request.getParameter("userId");
    String searchProductName = request.getParameter("productName");
    String searchQuantity = request.getParameter("quantity");
    String searchPrice = request.getParameter("price");
    String searchDdes = request.getParameter("des");
    String searchStock = request.getParameter("stock");
    String searchDate = request.getParameter("date");

    Product updateableUser = new Product();

    updateableUser.setPname(searchProductName);
    updateableUser.setPquantity(searchQuantity);
    updateableUser.setPprice(searchPrice);
    updateableUser.setPdes(searchDdes);
    updateableUser.setPstock(searchStock);
    updateableUser.setPdate(searchDate);


    System.out.println("PRODUCT ID += " + searchId);
    productService.updateUser(updateableUser);
    return this.searchUsers(request, map, null, null);
}
```

My DaoImpl

```
public void updateUser(Product product) {
        EntityManager entityManager = transactionManager.getEntityManagerFactory().createEntityManager();
        EntityTransaction transaction = entityManager.getTransaction();
        try {
            transaction.begin();

            entityManager.merge(product);
            transaction.commit();
        } catch (Exception exc) {
            exc.printStackTrace();
            if (transaction.isActive())
                transaction.rollback();
        } finally {
            if (entityManager.isOpen())
                entityManager.close();
        }
        System.out.println("MANA UG UPDATE");
    }
```

I try this statement in my Controller:
updateableUser.setPquantity(searchQuantity+searchStock);

But when i have 10quantity and i input 5stock the result will become 105.
What will i do to add this two values??

Comment: Convert them from `String` (for which `+` is the concatenation) to some number format. `int` or `long` will probably be suitable. And after that, make sure you **sanitize your inputs**!

Comment: result= result/10quantity + result%5stock

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like the + symbol is being used on two strings rather than two integers which is concatenating the strings together instead of adding them together as Integers. You would need to make them into Integers in order to add them together in this manner.

E.g.

```
int quantity = Integer.valueOf(searchQuantity)+ Integer.valueOf(searchStock)
updateableUser.setPquantity(String.valueOf(quantity));
```

Of course, this might throw an exception unless you have already validated that they numbers are actually integers.

Comment: Thank you sir. what a big help for a beginner.